# how do you add pdf files to a list in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, xpdf

I am trying to analyze pdf files in R. Following the instructions on data.library.virginia.edu/reading-pdf-files-into-r-for-text-mining/ . The first few steps worked out fine but i realize that i have to somehow connect the PDF files to the list in R. I think i have correctly used the instructions to use the function xpdf in windows.

Below is my coding in R so far.

```
library(tm)
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")

Rpdf <- readPDF(control = list(text = "-layout"))
Comments <- Corpus(URISource(files), 
                   readerControl = list(reader = Rpdf))
Comments.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Comments, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                                            stopwords = TRUE,
                                                            tolower = TRUE,
                                                            stemming = TRUE,
                                                            removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                                            bounds = list(global = c(3, Inf))))
```

This is my first question ever on this forum (quite the beginner), so if anything is unclear or i formulated this question wrong i would gladly hear it.

Comment: So you want to filter several unrelated directories for PDFs, append the findings to a single list of filenames?

Comment: Yes, i think a single list of filenames would be great.

Comment: go to an appropriate parent directory, use the `dir` function: `dir(".", recursive=TRUE, pattern = "*.pdf")`